# JW player not working properly on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, flash, jwplayer

i am getting a weird error. i have wordpress site and jw flash player plugin. the problem is when page loads, autostart videos doesnt play, just keeping loading and loading but if i pause it and play it agian it works fine. 
same with the other click to start vidoes , if i play first time , video just keep loading but if i pause it and play agian it work fine.

first i thought may b its a server bandwidth problem, i uploaded video on amazon s3 but still same problem.
i have added jwplayer manually but same problem.

here is the site http://www.mindsetmasteryexperience.com/

first video is from amazon s3 and play with wordpress plugin.
second video is hosted on server and play with manually added jw player.
i am using flv formate.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, Problem was with file format. i converted mp4 videos to flv by using online tools. videos didnt converted properly so that is why jw player wasnt playing them first time. when i used original flv video , it worked fine and played video in first go.

Thanks